# How to request index of daily candle close

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to get index of daily candle close.

I'm building an indicator which draws a horizontal line on 1 minute chart.
for example since day's opening it draws line to 1440 bars forward (because 1 day has 1440 minutes)
However when I change timeframe it's being broke.
Is there a way to automatically spot index for close of daily candle?
doesn't matter if I use 1m 5m 15m 1h 4h chart it will draw line until end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of struggles and trying long codes I can't believe solution was that much simple. I was not sure if it's forbidden to answer my own question but I have never seen this question here before so I will answer. Maybe it will help someone in future. (if answering your own question is forbidden, I would like to ask admins to close question or delete what is needed)

```
---Calculations for pivot----
    day_op = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) //if daily open price changes it means new daily candle arrived
    day_cl = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time_close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on) //get close time of daily bar 
    
    if ta.change(day_op) //if daily open price changed 
        a = line.new(time, pivot, day_cl , pivot, color=color.black, style=line.style_solid, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

here we draw new line "a" when new day started, it gets pivot calculations of previous day.
it draws from time of day_opening until day_cl. (close time of the day)
a warning if you use `xlox=xloc.bar_index`  this line won't draw correctly!

Comment: Actually, I looked for something else and just stumbled about this question. So far, solved it differently since I didnt knew about 'time_close' being available. Thanks.